# How do I use a loop/variables in sed, awk or bash to add the contents of 1 set of files into another set of files?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to work out how I can add the contents of a set of `files1` defined by

```
ls /home/dir1/*-split.csv.*
```

And then add the contents of each file from `files1` into another set of files e.g. `files2` defined by

```
ls /home/dir2/*.py.*.py
```

Both sets of `files1` and `files2` will always have the same number of files in them.

I have managed to get this work for 1 file using

```
files1=($home/dir1/'*'-split.csv.'*')
grep -h '^[^\s]*' $files1 | xargs -I '{}' sed -i  s'/userid/{}/' /home/dir2/*.py.*.py
```

But I don't know how to turn this into a loop so that the files from `files1` are inserted into the files in `files2`.

As above, the sed statement looks to replace `'userid'` in `files2` which are located at `/home/dir2/*.py.*.py` with the contents of the file in `files1` located at `/home/dir1/*-split.csv.*`.

All the files in `files2` have `'userid'` in them and this is the string to replace each time with the contents of a file from `files1`.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

---

**Edit**

Hi guys, thank you for your comments and pushing me for a better explanation!

Hopefully this sheds some more light on things... list of files like this...

```
ls /home/dir1/*-split.csv.*
just-users-split.csv.aa
just-users-split.csv.ab
just-users-split.csv.ac
just-users-split.csv.ad
```

Each file contains a single line of text e.g.

```
cat *.aa
"userPhD","userdegree","user123",

cat *.ab
"userxyz","userabc","user456"
```

In files2, I have a corresponding list of 4 files e.g.

```
ls /home/dir2/*.py.*.py
twud.py.1.py
twud.py.2.py
twud.py.3.py
twud.py.4.py
```

All of the `*.py.*.py` files are a copy of each other and contain a `91 line` python script.

I then want to insert the contents of

`just-users-split.csv.aa` into `twud.py.1.py`

`just-users-split.csv.ab` into `twud.py.2.py`

`just-users-split.csv.ac` into `twud.py.3.py`

`just-users-split.csv.ad` into `twud.py.4.py`

The inserting can either be done at the top or bottom of the *.py file, or in an ideal world, the contents of `just-users-split.csv.aa` would be inserted on line 33 to replace the current string `ids = "userid".`

Finally, in this example there are 4 files to loop through but in other situations, it may be that there are 5, 10 or 20 pairs of files to loop through.

Does this make any more sense?

Comment: I find the description of your problem rather confusing.

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm just trying to insert the contents of one set of files into another set but I need to do this for multiple files - does this help?

Comment: For me it's still quite confusing. Better if you show some input files with a few lines each and what you expect the output to be. Just show the minimum possible, but enough so that an answer to the abbreviated problem could be extended by you to the general case. (For example, maybe it would be enough to show two files from `files1` and two from `files2` with just one line of content each.)

Comment: Part of my confusion is, how do you know which files from files1 to put into which files within files2??

Comment: How are you matching files? do you want all content from first list of files to be inserted to all of the second list of files?  Or, is it one-to-one?  which requires a mapping.

Comment: In `files1` if I run `ls /home/dir1/*-split.csv.*` I get

just-users-split.csv.aa
just-users-split.csv.ab etc.

Each file contains a single line of text e.g.

`cat *.aa`
`"jennyarntzenPhD","chambda","SlickTrilly",`

In files2, I have a corresponding list of 4 files e.g.

`ls /home/dir2/*.py.*.py`

`twud.py.1.py`
`twud.py.2.py` etc.

The *.py.*.py files are a 91 line copy of each other

I then want to insert the contents of the 4 files

just-users-split.csv.aa into twud.py.1.py
just-users-split.csv.ab into twud.py.2.py etc.

I might have 10 or 20 pairs of files to loop

Comment: @jas , I've added copies of the files from `files1` and `files2` into the question @grail , hopefully the updated question answers how to identify the files from `files1` and `files2` @karakfa it's basically a one-to-one matching e.g `just-users-split.csv.aa` into `twud.py.1.py` and `just-users-split.csv.ab` into `twud.py.2.py` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

files1=($(ls /home/dir1/*-split.csv.*))
files2=($(ls /home/dir2/*.py.*.py))

for (( i = 0; i < ${#files1[@]}; i++ )); do
  content=($(sed -n 1p ${files1[$i]}))     
  sed -i "33s/.*/ids = $content/" ${files2[$i]} 
done
```

The variable `i` in the for loop is in the range `[0,n)`, `n` being the size of files1/files2 arrays.

In every round of the for loop, the variable `content` gets assigned to the first line of the file in `dir1`. This variable is then used to replace line 33 of maching file's content within `dir2`.

For example:

```
$ cat -n /home/dir1/just-users-split.csv.ab | sed -n '1p'
     1  "userPhD","userdegree","user123"
$ cat -n /home/dir2/twud.py.1.py | sed -n '33p'
    33  ids = "userid"
$ ./script
$ cat -n /home/dir2/twud.py.1.py | sed -n '33p'
    33  ids = "userPhD","userdegree","user123"
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much Alexander!

Comment: The output of `ls` is sorted by default.  You should generally [avoid parsing `ls` output in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @tripleee Good point .. I've edited my post above. Thanks!
\@Bruce You're welcome :)